# How to Create Non-Stop Loop to skip Error: Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I created a Python Selenium script to filter out URLs that have the specific elements. Almost Everything was working fine. But I am continuously getting some non-resolving exceptions, after these exceptions, my script stops:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

And

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I tried to create loops. The loops work for other exceptions such as NoSuchElement Exception or any other but the issue is with the WebDriverException. I am unable to resolve this. I also added "Continue" in the loop but it also failed.
I am reading a list of URLs from a CSV file.

Here is my code:

```
from logging import exception
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import csv
import selenium.common.exceptions

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_argument("--headless")

def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        rawUrls = line["URL"]
        print(rawUrls)

        chromedriver = ("chromedriver")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=options)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.get(rawUrls)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
         
            
        
                  

        try:
            name = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'author')
            email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
            
            print("PASSED, ALL REQUIRED ELEMENTS FOUND")
            
            filterAll = driver.current_url
            with open("HAS_ALL_ELEMENTS.txt", "a") as r:
                print(filterAll, file=r)
        except WebDriverException or NoSuchElementException or Exception:   
        
                       
            #print('Exception:',exception)
            print("NONE OF THE ELEMENTS FOUND, ERROR!")
            nothingFound = driver.current_url
            with open("NO_ELEMENTS.txt", "a") as n:
                print(nothingFound, file=n)
        continue          
           
        
         
                    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open ("RAW_URLs.csv") as url_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(url_obj)
        csv_url_reader(url_obj)
```

Actually, I want to create the script unstoppable. If there is any exception it should skip that URL and switch to the other one. The script should keep going. I tried many solutions available on Stack Overflow but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the WebDriverException comes from the line `driver.get(rawUrls)`, move that line into the `try except` block.